# Error in Generating Alphanumeric ID VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I was trying to Generate a unique ID by concatenating the User company + auto-generated ID

My output for my alphanumeric is "SNC001" but when I tried to generate the next ID I got the following error:

> Conversion from string "SNC001" to type 'Integer' is not valid.

PS: the "SNC" came from this frm_Main_Menu.lblCompany.Text

```
Dim maxid As Object
Dim strid As String
Dim intid As Integer
Dim cmdid As New MySqlCommand

cmdid.Connection = cnn_MYSQL
cmdid.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(printed_id) as maxid FROM imports"
maxid = cmdid.ExecuteScalar

If maxid Is DBNull.Value Then
    intid = "001"
Else
    strid = CType(maxid, String)
    intid = CType(strid, String)
    intid = intid + 1
End If

Dim autoid As String = frm_Main_Menu.lblCompany.Text & intid.ToString().PadLeft(3, "001")

Dim cmd66 As New MySqlCommand
cmd66.Connection = cnn_MYSQL
cmd66.CommandText = "UPDATE imports " & _
    " SET printed='" & "Y" & "', printed_id='" & autoid & "'" & _
    " WHERE TIN = '" & id_selected &"'"
cmd66.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: On which statement exactly is this error being thrown?

Comment: `intid = CType(strid, String)` => use `Convert.ToInt32(strid.Substring(3, 3))` instead.

Comment: in this line intid = CType(strid, String) @Paul Karam

Comment: Yeah, @TetsuyaYamamoto gave you a perfect explanation of your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning entire ID segment which has `String` type to `Integer` field/variable on this line, which is totally wrong and causing `InvalidCastException`:

```vb
intid = CType(strid, String) ' throws conversion error
```

The correct way is chopping off the prefix using `Substring()` starting from numeric part (i.e. 4th element which has index of 3) and convert the remainder to integer with either `Convert.ToInt32()` or `Integer.Parse()` method:

```vb
' using Convert.ToInt32
intid = Convert.ToInt32(strid.Substring(3, 3))

' alternative with Integer.Parse
intid = Integer.Parse(strid.Substring(3, 3))
```

**Side note:**

Better to use parameterized query instead of string concatenation to build the query, see following example below:

```vb
cmd66.CommandText = "UPDATE imports SET printed = 'Y', printed_id = @autoid WHERE TIN = @id_selected"
cmd66.Parameters.Add("@autoid", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = autoid
cmd66.Parameters.Add("@id_selected", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = id_selected
cmd66.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: ive got an error saying "Input string was not in a correct format."

in this line intid = Integer.Parse(strid.Substring(3, 3))

Comment: In which line that error occurred? The same line as before or in other line?

Comment: same line as before

Comment: Check the string first by outputting `strid.Substring(3, 3)` in debug - are you get exactly "001"? If it's not, then adjust that string first, because `Integer.Parse(strid.Substring(3, 3))` should working fine for 3 remainder digits.

Comment: I've a new error saying "startIndex cannot be larger than length of string. Parameter name: startIndex"    same line as before

Comment: Try using `Length` property to check if the string exactly contains 6 alphanumeric chars, e.g. `If maxid Is DBNull.Value OrElse strid.Length < 6 Then ...`. In short, put a check against `Length` before using `Substring`.